# How can i implement a background "Timer" in PHP of my page that checks something every X time

Tags: php, blogs

I want to implement something that do every X time some actions. I want that this thread worker are always executing in my server (PHP).

For example:

I have a blog and i want that someone process deletes comments with keyword "XXXX". I want that this process can sleep every X minutes and when it wakes up, gain, it will going to delete the comments.

I dont want the solution, i only want how can implement this type of process in PHP server (Apache).

Comment: build a script that does what you want, and trigger it with a cron job at your desired interval.

Comment: if you have access to your server's terminal, cron is better suited for this, php is not designed to be a daemon

Answer (score 8):

You can use a cron job to run a PHP script every x minutes etc

All you need to do is make a PHP file to do what you need, and then point the cron to the PHP file and it will run for whatever time you specify

If you use something like Plesk or cPanel cronjobs are built in and very easy to use.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: Thank you man, have your points. Also i have discovered that Wordpress implements cron job in its framework, is very easy to implement.